# Is it a bad practice to do search using post request?

Tags: sql, post, get, sql-injection

-I'm doing a shopping list search by name. If the name matches then it shows all the available items from the database. Is it a bad practice to implement search using post request? I've checked it's perfectly working and not injectable.

-A bonus question, is there any way user can drop (delete) table if the search field is vulnerable to sql injection?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not bad practice to code it that way. Another option would be to use asynchronous JavaScript using a REST call that returns data. But either way, you're going to hit the database with a web request.

If your code allows SQL injection, then an attacker can do anything to the database that is allowed for the user account that is used to create the connection - including possibly dropping tables.

One common way to prevent SQL injection is to build all SQL statements using parameterized queries, such as the ones implemented with JDBC or ODBC. Be careful when building SQL from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, that's clear. If I'm not wrong if it's injectable then the user can drop table as long as it's a POST request? GET request shouldn't modify the database as it's just getting the data.

Comment: In the REST model, you're correct that GET shouldn't update the database. But that's up to the programmer to enforce.